# Does significance level of individual coefficients in ARDL really matter?

Tags: statistical-significance, ardl

Does significance level of individual coefficients in ARDL really matter? Some papers dont mention the p-values of individual coefficients while others retain non-significant variables in their final models. I have asked this question in other forums long time ago, but no answer yet. Wishing a good answer. I have perhaps studied all tutorial available over the web starting Dave Giles with comments but none answers this.

Comment: This question is more general than just the ARDL models. I would look around Cross Validated searching for something like "should I keep insignificant variables". You will find a few threads with a few answers, possibly different opinions, but hopefully in the end you will be able to decide for yourself what to do with statistical significance. Also, it depends what you want to do with your model. If you want to use it for forecasting, then statistical significance is not too interesting a property.

Comment: I am working on supply response of selected agricultural crops using price and non-price factors and ARDL Bounds testing approach. I have been suggested that once the Bounds test has been cleared (F value higher than upper bound) I dont need to care what the p-values for each individual regresser say, and I just have to interpret the coefficients like we do in  OLS. I dont want to forecast, just need to see the independent effects of price and non-price variables on production of ith crop. Any suggestions?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that inference after model selection is very complicated and often intractable. Although it is standard practice to do model selection first and then do inference as if the selected model was fixed in advance of seeing the data, that does not mean it makes sense. (Yes, thousands of papers have wrong results in them just because of the neglected effects of model selection on inference.) So if you want to do inference in a relatively sound way, keep the model as is. Then you at least avoid the mistake of neglecting the effects of model selection on inference.